# Angular2 RC6 with angular-cli / How to upgrade angular2 version in projects

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I just did a fresh install of angular-cli on a newly installed machineץ When running `ng --version` I get:

```
date it to a more recent version.
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10
node: 6.5.0
os: win32 x64
```

Which seems to be to latest update (according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli)

When I create a new project using `ng new MyProject` I see that it uses `rc4` - and I was reading somewhere that `rc6` is already supported and that people successfully worked with it (but no technical details on how to upgrade).

My `package.json` dependencies are the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
}
```

How can I upgrade my project (new project and existing projects) to `rc6` and still work with angular-cli ?

Comment: For a start, you should use `@webpack`; that gets you RC5 at least.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. how do I do that?

Comment: Read the guidance in the GitHub repo!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
A guide to [Upgrading from angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.10 to the angular-cli@webpack](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14) on Angular-Cli repo @ GitHub.

---

Change `package.json` **dependencies** to be like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/router": "~3.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.12",
"@angularclass/form-validators": "^1.0.11",
"@angularclass/resolve-angular-routes": "^1.0.8",
"@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.1",
"@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
"core-js": "^2.2.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
"zone.js": "~0.6.17"}
```

And **dev-dependencies** to be like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.28",
"@types/node": "^4.0.30",
"assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
"cross-spawn": "^4.0.0",
"es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
"ignore-loader": "^0.1.1",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"string-replace-loader": "github:gdi2290/string-replace-loader",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
"ts-helpers": "github:gdi2290/ts-helpers",
"ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
"ts-node": "^1.2.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.0-beta",
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22",
"webpack-dashboard": "0.0.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.0"}
```

**Or** replace your `package.json`with this one from Angular2-Seed on Github: https:// github. com/AngularClass/angular2-seed/blob/master/package.json

***Note that:***

- Angular2 uses core-js instead of es6-shim
- Webpack is preferred over angular-cli system.js ([check this discussion](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/586))

Comment: this is assuming you're choosing webpack over angular-cli

Comment: @developer82 angular CLI is moving to Webpack, so it's not really a choice

Comment: @jonrsharpe but it would still be angular-cli - it would just utilize webpack, with the ease of angular-cli...

Comment: @developer82 I've updated the answer; angular-cli now with webpack: "angular-cli@webpack"